# i am trying to upload images on server using android volley (in the form of strings)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, image-uploading

The quality of images is very bad and size is around 25-35 kbs.
how do I increase its quality.

is it because I am sending images as string  ?
can string converted to image have high quality ?

I wanna send full quality images, how do I go about it ?

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void  uploadImage(){
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                //Getting Image Name
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                params.put(KEY_NAME, "name");

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: `quality of images is very bad and size is around 25-35 kbs`. Then why do you send such images? If an image is bad quality it will stay bad.

Comment: I am sending image by clicking it from my nexus 5 -_-

Comment: You really are a magician!

Comment: size and quality - on the database side :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not get that image from data, it is always a low quality image. Try using a file path and get the image from file path.

Open Camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(path));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

And when you return to onActivityResult the image will be stored to your defined path. You can get the high resolution image from there. Or you can also use a function to get last captured image

```
private String getLastImagePath() {
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
            null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        return fullPath;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: is it helpful for you ? if it, than accept as right answer so any one else get benefit from it !! @Bawa

Comment: I am having trouble integerating it in my project.. as soon as I am done..i'll mark it correct , I am pretty sure what you said will work.

Comment: how do I use the image path to get my image :(

Comment: Set you path where u want to store the image :)

Comment: can you come on chat ? if you are available, because the work is official and its urgent for me,

Comment: Sorry bro,  i am also in office working with lots of stuff !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108745/discussion-between-bawa-and-jhaman-das).